# Bitrise local path certificate and provisional profile

Tags: workflow, bitrise

Can anyone provide me a way to assign the path of my profile and certificate which is already in my cloned code to bitrise.(using git)
right now, i am giving
{“mapped_to”:"$BITRISE_PROVISION_URL",“value”:“file://./profile/bitdist.mobileprovision | file://./profile/bitdev.mobileprovision”,“is_expand”:true}
but it is not working…[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should not include the leading `$` in `{“mapped_to”:"$BITRISE_PROVISION_URL"` - it should be just `{“mapped_to”:"BITRISE_PROVISION_URL"`.